# Typescript: Force a deep partial assigned property to have the right type

Tags: typescript

I have created a `DeepPartial` type in Typescript:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
};
```

And use this functionality to assign data to an object. So far so good!

```
class Order {
   constructor(obj: DeepPartial<Order>) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
  id: string = '';
  lines: OrderLine[] = [];

  getInfo() {
    return 'Order ID:'+this.id;
  }
}

const order = new Order({id:'982734'});
console.log(order.getInfo()); // OK (Order ID:982734")
```

But now I also would like to assign order lines to this object. The `OrderLine` itself looks like this:

```
class OrderLine {
   constructor(obj: DeepPartial<OrderLine>) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
  product: string = '';

  getInfo() {
    return 'Product name:'+this.product;
  }
}
```

The partial copy itself looks fine, because I'm able to access the products:

```
const order = new Order({
  id:'982734',
  lines: [
    {product:'pizza'},
    {product:'cheese'}
  ]
});
console.log(order.getInfo()); // OK (Order ID:982734")

order.lines.forEach(line => {
  console.log(line.product); // OK (pizza + cheese)
})
```

But when I try to access the `getInfo()` on the `OrderLine` I see the error message "(line.getInfo is not a function)"

```
order.lines.forEach(line => {
  console.log(line.getInfo()); // NOK (line.getInfo is not a function)
})
```

It looks like the issue is that `order.lines` is not an instance of `OrderLine`, but how can I fix this with a deep partial copy without casting order.lines explicitly? [Example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=3&pln=41&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgAoEMBOwCWyA2AeAKgHxQC8UA3gFBQ1QDaiUGAdlANYQgD2AZlPgF0A-AC5Y8JGkw4CDAYQDclAL5LKAY2zIAztqgB5VABMIqCtRrquzbcFQBXdcC6oAFFwBGAKzFwEKdCw8QxNUQgBKc1oDbwgnADodbQwAc2ZXYAALDG0AGihPL3ClGmULDCMxW1QWFNIoAHIGkqhsFghtMRDTABl2ugF6gbUaFIhgAElmHi5XSKpo1HH7VFYG7rMJmBEGgGosnPiKlrKyjS1dA2Ne9qjLa2rHZzdC3wkA6WDr1D7mCAi7jR9LEEklUukDnkCt5ihYyjQwKguEYnlU7LV6k0RlAxpNprN5hYaEtgCs1ogkSinFBmMgALYQHb7bLaeKI5FPE4qSgaB7AArfep-ADuV1CrgWTEqDQAnAAOABMAHYAMwAFgauQsbT%20nXoRIo7KpwB2YAwAC9zcgGsotdFyEbUQ11Jl4NoIDaLAIVLCrDYuNgIPFsFwUu5vvFcVMZnNilAAPTxgwAaSgrg2UC2InlyvVACJwjyXKFg%201WTNUABRZAu1w66AkYiSv3aANBkNh%20tsylPOOJlNps2W5BQXZQF1uiCF5SFyjF0yl3XxCvV2v10hNiwttvB0N19qR8bRgl9pMAOX0qf3f0PeJmTD0zC4-JHPHszCcGGs08LQA)

Comment: Compiles fine on my playground with tsc v4.2.3, what version are you using?

Comment: Strange, I see this error in the logs: `[ERR]: line.getInfo is not a function`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought you were getting a compile time error. It does it indeed fail at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not really converting lines object within Orders to be of type OrderLine. Updating your code as below will work

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
};

class Order {
   constructor(obj: DeepPartial<Order>) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
    this.lines = this.lines.map(line =>  new OrderLine(line));
  }
  id: string = '';
  lines: OrderLine[] = [];

  getInfo() {
    return 'Order ID:'+this.id;
  }
}
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=45&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgAoEMBOwCWyA2AeAKgHxQC8UA3gFBQ1QDaiUGAdlANYQgD2AZlPgF0A-AC5Y8JGkw4CDAYQDclAL5LKAY2zIAztqgB5VABMIqCtRrquzbcFQBXdcC6oAFFwBGAKzFwEKdCw8QxNUQgBKc1oDbwgnADodbQwAc2ZXYAALDG0AGihPL3ClaKyc%20OwWCD0yMu0KqvqAW2QwV0rmaBJiKE6AdwNjUwAZKvaq8OKLZQsMIzFbVBYU0igAcjWSqA7qsRCRqroBVaO1GhSIYABJZh4uV0iqaNRL%201RWNf2zK5gRNYBqOrxOZbGYzDRaXSDUKjTpRSzWRaOZxuQq%20CQBaTBIaoWEQCLwmj6WIJJKpdJ1fKFKY0GY0MCoLhGZELOzLVYbM5QC7XW73R4WGgvYBvD6IRnMpy9ZBNCB-QHZeoMpnI0EqSgaRHAAo41b9aGmVxPJjzNYATgAHAAmADsAGYACxrXIWHbaMR0QUUZWS4B-MAYABegeQa2ULui5B9LLW6ky8G0EDDFgEKimVhsXGwEAqXBS7hx8R5NzuD2KUAA9BWDABpKCuL5QH4iS22x0AInCGpcoQanXqd1QAFFkHHxnDuvCM9osznsHnxzno05y1Xa-WA8HkFB-lA4wmIF3lF3KD3TH3qvFByOxztSMRjdPZ7n8zsi5cS-zV9WAHL6OuLu%20vJ3EwejMFw2rbjw9jME4GDWEeXZAA)

Comment: Do you think there is a way to solve this without converting the object manually?

Comment: It would be difficult to create new instances without knowing what constructor function they would refer too